# How to listen on browser requests (proxy, addon...)?

Tags: c#, .net, browser, proxy, add-on

I wanted to know what is the best way to write an agent on Win platform that will be able to monitor browser's communication.

**scenario:** monitor the user access to predefined url on Chrome, FireFox and IE. On each hit I send the stats to a server with some data (page title).

**The ways I found so far are proxy and browser addons.** Each has it's own advantages and disadvantages. The main disadvantage of the proxy way is handling of HTTPS communication. The addon disadvantage is the installation (need to install on every browser) and cross-browser support.

Is there another way? some service I can write with .net that will automatically hook on a browser when it is started?

Thanks you.

Comment: there are lot of applications are available in market like http sniffer etc....
why don't you use any one of them ?

Comment: Thanks, but I need to write it myself and add some functionality. The available sniffers will not be suited for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have only two choices - an http proxy, or to write a plugin for every browser.  That plugin *could* just forward data via network to a central service, leaving you with the challenge of coming up with a common set of data that all browsers can provide, plus learning all the plugin models.

In my opinion, though, the only real option is an HTTP(s) proxy because otherwise you have to keep updating your plugins every time browsers change, or deal with the fact that new browsers can come along and be used.

Certainly you won't find a 'user is browsing a url in some browser' event in the OS - all it knows is that a socket connection has been opened on some local port to a remote server's port 80/443 (or whatever).

So I strongly suggest building on top of the excellent work that's behind Fiddler and use the Fiddler Core.

http://www.telerik.com/fiddler/fiddlercore

For https you have to decrypt and re-encrypt with a different certificate.  The information that you need is just not available without actually unpacking the request.  Fiddler achieves this by opening it's own SSL tunnel to the target server on the client's behalf, whilst acting as an SSL server to the client under a different certificate.  So long as the certificate that it uses is fully trusted by the client, no problems occur.

That said, it means that the user cannot personally verify the identify of the target site - therefore your system would have to assume worst case scenario for any invalid SSL certificates and block the connection.

Comment: Thanks, this is a valid option but I wish to avoid SSL termination. I'm trying to be as transparent as possible (except for the initial install).

Comment: Well you can just not have an SSL listener - it could be argued that you should not be installing something that can sniff users' SSL traffic anyway.  If you're not keen than you are going to have to write plugins for each browser

Comment: An SSL listener is a must, I don't care about the data that is transmitted nor the GET/POST params - just the URL and page title. I hoped there is some eventing mechanism in Win that allows me to get notified when something is wired by any browser

Comment: As I said - you can do an SSL listener, but *the only way you can get the url is to decrypt it and re-encrypt it with a different cert*, all the request data outside of the target IP and port is stored ***inside*** the request.  There is no OS-wide 'browsing a URL' event - it's http(s) traffic, and that's it.  You have to write a proxy OR a plugin for *every* browser, they are your two choices.

Comment: I was afraid of that, really hoped there is something I missed. I now have to choose between development for each browser (there are frameworks that might help) or to be more intrusive using the proxy approach. Thank you very much for your help and suggestions.